# How to let Delphi read from certain line to a certain line in a text file

Tags: delphi, text-files

**I just started Delphi and I'm not using database right now, and this is just a exercise that I'm doing (text file)**

My program's form is setup like this:

[image]

And this is what's in my Text file:

[image]

**Description:** If the user wants to view a chess match, they have to enter the Chess match name then the program must looks for the Chess Match name then read everything from that line until it reaches the "-------------------------", then it must display it on to the Rich Edit component

**Here is my code:**

```
begin
  AssignFile(tFile, 'ChessRecords.txt');
  Reset(tFile);
  while not Eof(tFile) do
    begin
      sGameName:= '';
      Readln(tFile, sLine);
      iPos:= Pos('/', sLine);
      sGameName:= Copy(sLine, 1,iPos-1);
      if sGameName = edtGameName.Text then
        begin
          repeat
            redOut.Lines.Add(sLine);
          until (sLine = '-------------------------');
        end;
      end;
    end;    
end.
```

Comment: Who is still teaching AssignFile/Readln/Reset in the 21st century? Please use TStringList.

Comment: Your comment makes me rethink about the level of the South African educational system is currently on...

Comment: You have to read all of the lines from the beginning

Comment: Doesn't "Reset" do the job as to read the text file from the beginning?

Comment: Looks like you're almost there. Think about what else might need to happen inside that loop. Like, what would make them value of `sLine` change from one iteration to the next? What specific problem are you having with your project?

Comment: "makes me rethink"  Don't lose too much sleep about it.  Pascal, the language Delphi is based upon, was designed as a teaching language.  Whether to use traditional file I/O or StringLists is virtually an irrelevance compared to the fact that you are learning to code in a language that doesn't encourage novices to get into bad habits.  You can soon catch up with 21st century ways of doing things later.

Comment: Is there anyway to add count to "readLn()"?

Comment: You can use variables to count whatever you want.

Comment: @StijnSanders there is nothing wrong in AssignFile and Readln. Try to read 4GB text log with your TStringList!

Comment: @ZENsan: "To the man with a hammer everything looks like a nail." TStringList is indeed not for 4GB+ files, but TFileStream handles them fine. Also, when I expect more than 100KB I switch to [SQLite](https://github.com/stijnsanders/TSQLite)

Comment: @StijnSanders: For a certain tasks AssignFile, Read/Write are still very efficient and simple enough. However it's quite rare case. So no "hammers" please.

Comment: @StijnSanders  that is a good idea for relatively small files, say not more than 500MB - but if it is then LOADING the whole file into memory might become a burden if itself. Granted there are things like `TTextReader` and there are third-party text file processing libs as well...

Comment: Reading large files into memory makes no sense *unless* you need *massive* simultaneous random access to much or all of the file. Even then it's highly recommended to use [file mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your `repeat until` loop does not read from the file (`Readln()`) anymore - you also have to do that (and check for `Eof()` as well). Likewise each time you call the function you can also do an `Inc( iLine )`, but I don't see a reason why you want to count lines.

**Rob Kennedy**, **MartynA** and **ZENsan** are right: your approach is not up to date, but rock solid to still execute in 20 years.